# 2 Installations of MYSQL - one allows subquery in View definition, one doesn't

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have 2 MYSQL installations. In one local install, the NVL, having Subquery in From clause in View work but in the other server (which is on AWS) none of that works. Is there some config that needs to be changed?

Comment: What are the MySQL versions?

Comment: Hi. My local version is 5.7.12 and the view with subquery works on this. NVL also works in this. But the AWS version (the other install) is 5.5.49. My query is CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT TOPICID, USERID, CART, KEYID, IRANK, RANK
FROM(SELECT A.TOPICID, A.USERID, A.CART, A.KEYID, A.IRANK, (SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) FROM table1 B
WHERE CONCAT(B.USERID, B.CART) = CONCAT(A.USERID,A.CART) AND B.IRANK < A.IRANK) RANK
FROM table1 AS A) AS X WHERE X.RANK<=15
ORDER BY X.USERID, X.RANK;

Answer (score 0):

From [Changes in MySQL 5.7.7 (2015-04-08, Release Candidate)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-7.html):

> Previously, view definitions were not permitted to contain derived
>   tables (subqueries) in the FROM clause. This restriction has now been
>   lifted.

Looks like you need to upgrade your AWS MySQL.